# Вложенные запросы и Unknown column in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, mysqli

Есть два SQL-запроса. Первый выполняется без проблем:

```
SELECT DISTINCT self.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ps_orders` 
        WHERE self.`id_customer` != 'NULL' 
            AND `id_customer` = self.`id_customer`) AS orders_total 
    FROM `ps_module_actionssubscription` AS self 
    LIMIT 0,20;
```

А на второй запрос MySQL ругается `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'orders_total' in 'where clause'`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT self.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ps_orders` 
        WHERE self.`id_customer` != 'NULL' 
            AND `id_customer` = self.`id_customer`) AS orders_total 
    FROM `ps_module_actionssubscription` AS self 
    WHERE orders_total > 5 
    LIMIT 0,20;
```

Где ошибка во втором запросе?? Как правильно его записать, чтобы он возвращал только результаты по условию `WHERE`??

Comment: Попробуй заменить WHERE  на HAVING

Comment: ессна, как он сделает выборку из того, чего ещё нет. если хочется именно подобную структуру запроса, оберните его в SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT self.*, .... тогда уже order_total будет известен. и чего-то у меня сомнения на счет корректности !=NULL. Но вообщбе мало базовй инфы, отсюда нелепые предложения.

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, спасибо, заменить WHERE на HAVING помогло. Оформи как ответ, тогда поставлю галочку))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В документации **[en](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)/[ru](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/SELECT.html)** написано:

> It is not allowable to refer to a  column alias in a WHERE clause,  because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE  clause is executed. See **[Section B.1.5.4, “Problems with Column Aliases”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)**.

тобишь

> Псевдонимы столбцов нельзя использовать в выражении WHERE, поскольку находящиеся в столбцах величины на момент выполнения WHERE могут быть еще не определены. **[See section A.5.4 Проблемы с alias.](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Problems_with_alias.html)**

Вместе с этим

> выражение `HAVING` может ссылаться на любой столбец или псевдоним, упомянутый в выражении `select_expression`. `HAVING` отрабатывается последним, непосредственно перед отсылкой данных клиенту, и без какой бы то ни было оптимизации.

и

> Псевдонимы можно использовать для ссылки на столбец в GROUP BY, ORDER BY или в части **HAVING**, а также для лучшего именования столбцов

Получается для псевдонимов в данном случае следует применять `HAVING` вместо `WHERE`.

---

P.S. Для небольшого ознакомления предлагаю ознакомиться с вопросом на enSO **[WHERE vs HAVING](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2905292/6104996)**